# C++ template class static members initialization

Tags: c++

Can please someone help me with a strange problem in C++. I would like to have a static member in template class. That static member is another class, which I have to initialize somehow. I do not know where and how to initialize that class. I have made a small example of a problem I have. The sample does compile but not link because the static member is obviously nowhere to be found. Where did I go wrong? Where could I initialize static member. Static member is not a simple variable where I can only assign a value to it. In my program, I have to call even more functions in order to initialize the static member.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class TemplateClass
{
protected:
    T1 t1;
    static T2 t2;

public:
    TemplateClass ();
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
TemplateClass<T1, T2>::TemplateClass ()
{
    TemplateClass<T1, T2>::t2.initialize (10);
}

class T1Sample
{
private:
    int i;

public:
    T1Sample () : i (1) {};
    int get_i () { return i; };
};

class T2Sample
{
private:
    int i;

public:
    T2Sample () : i (0) {};
    void initialize (int x) { i = x; };
    int get_i () { return i; };
};

class DerivedClass : TemplateClass<T1Sample, T2Sample>
{
private:
    int z;

public:
    DerivedClass () { z = t1.get_i () + TemplateClass<T1Sample, T2Sample>::t2.get_i (); };
    int get_z () { return z; };
};

int main ()
{
    DerivedClass d;
    std::cout << d.get_z () << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to make it static?

Comment: Because I only need one instance and I need to use it in static functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add definition:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T2 TemplateClass<T1, T2>::t2{};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/528e2a1179022343)

Comment: Great! Thanks. I do not understand these `{}` at the end. I tried to compile it without those curly brackets, and it works, too.

Comment: @nobody: You might read documentations about [default_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) (without parenthesis) and other [initializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) for details.